# "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server" - Unable to resolve in Selenium/Python program using IE 11

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

After running my Selenium/Python program, browser opened with below message:

```
This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server
```

I have done below steps to resolve this:

1. In IE Options -> Security tab, Enable Protected Mode check box is ticked OFF in all zones: Internet, 
   Local Intranet, Trusted sites and Restricted sites. Also, in Advanced tab -> Security, ticked OFF the 
   check box: "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode" (Also, I tried with enabling this Protected Mode in all
   zones and in Advanced tab too).
2. My IEdriver (version 3.1.4) and Selenium web driver (version 3.1.4) are compatible (both are on same 
   version)
3. I tried above two, still I am getting the same message.

I have added below content to ignore Protected mode:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:/Selenium/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe',capabilities=caps)
```

Still, I am getting the same message after adding above code.

Any ideas? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as per design. When `IEDriverServer.exe` opens a new a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Internet Explorer** browsing session it navigates first to this page.

- Browser Snapshot

[image: IEDriverServer]

Once you initialize the browser through the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:/Selenium/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe',capabilities=caps)
```

next you can invoke the `get()` command to access any url. As an example:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Additionally you need to:

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://selenium.dev/downloads/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  latest [IEDriverServer v3.150.1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.150/) level.

  > **Note**: As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync and you must try to use both the binaries from the same **major** release.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Then, how can I handle this and launch my application?

Comment: @murthymrk Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Thats superb sir. Its launched the application now. And as you said, its first showing initial page for web driver server and then navigated to my site. Thanks for your quick response. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check if along IE ,Microsoft Edge browser also opens?if yes you need to uninstall Edge from your PC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).